# Facebook-php-sdk "Session has expired at unix time" with offline_access

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to make wall post to people's friends ( offline )
I took permissions for wall post and offline access. 
But most of the users have error when I try to offline wall post

> "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token:
>   Session has expired at unix time 1332190800. The current unix time is
>   1339803350. thrown in /home/......"

I think access token with offline access never expired ?

If it is expired, How can I take the new access token without touch the people ( offline )

I used this code

```
$post =  array(
        'access_token' => "ACCESSTOKEN",
        'message' => test",
        'link'          =>  'http://apps.facebook.com/xx',
        'description'   =>  'test'
         );


            $result = $facebook->api("/FRIENDS_ID/feed/",'post', $post);
```

Comment: I used ofline for people who I make wallpost to, is not online in facebook aplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook `offline_access` permission was deprecated last month. This feature is scheduled to be removed on July 5.

The new workflow requires you to get a long-term access token, which must be renewed every 60 days. There is more information about this here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/